# How to instruct Spring Boot to use application.properties file in test's resources when running tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following project structure for a Spring Boot App.

[image]

The issue is, whenever I run tests, the Spring Boot App uses the `application.properties` in the `config` folder in the root of the project instead of the `application.properties` in `src > test > resources` folder.

So as a hack when running tests, I scramble the name of the `application.properties` in the `config` folder.

How do I tell Spring Boot to use the `application.properties` in the test location when running tests without touching `config > application.properties`?

I don't want to keep renaming the file depending on whether I am running the application or running tests.

Comment: Try reaming it to application-test. properties

Comment: @Frischling, that didn't work. It throws an error 'Could not load Application Context'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a configuration file (**`application-test.properties`**) under your src/main/resources folder and then use
 **`@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")`** on your test

Answer (score 2):

Create a application-test.properties under the src/main/resources with your test configuration.

than use like below on your test

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this, it can solve your problem  [image: forder mark]

Comment: still hasn't worked. It's using the `application.properties` file in `config` folder